# Show $f(x) = x^2\sin{\frac{1}{x}} + \frac{x}{2}$ is not increasing on any open interval containing $0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

$f(x) = x^2\sin{\frac{1}{x}} + \frac{x}{2}$ for $x\not= 0$ and $f(0) = 0$.

Show $f$ is not increasing on any open interval containing $0$.

At first glance, we notice $f'(x) \le 0$ for some $x \in I$ where $I$ is any open interval. We can also recognize $f'(0) > 0$ by directly plugging in $0$ into the definition of a limit:

- $f'(x) = \lim_{x\to x_0}{\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}}$

We know that if $f'(0)>0$, then $f'(x)<0$ either above or below $0$.

However, at this point I get stuck on how to continue.

Comment: This is a very good and famous question related to "meaning of sign of derivative". +1

Comment: You can have a look here: http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/a-function-whose-derivative-at-0-is-one-but-which-is-not-increasing-near-0/

Answer (score 3):

Clearly you can note that $f'(0) = 1/2$ and $$f'(x) = 2x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) + \frac{1}{2}$$ if $x \neq 0$. As $x \to 0$ the first term $2x\sin(1/x)$ tends to $0$ and $\cos(1/x)$ oscillates between $-1$ and $1$. So as $x \to 0$ the derivative $f'(x)$ oscillates <strike>between</strike> around $-1 + 1/2$ and $1 + 1/2$ i.e. <strike>between</strike> around $-1/2$ and $3/2$. In more technical symbolism we write $$\liminf_{x \to 0}f'(x) = -\frac{1}{2},\,\limsup_{x \to 0}f'(x) = \frac{3}{2}$$ So any neighborhood of $0$ contains some points $a$ where $f'(a) > 0$ and some other points $b$ where $f'(b) < 0$. Thus it is not possible that $f$ in increasing in any neighborhood of $0$.

Note that $f'(0) = 1/2 > 0$ and yet there is no interval around $0$ in which $f$ is increasing. To quote Hardy in this matter:

"*If $f'(x)$ is positive at a single point $x_{0}$, then we can prove that $f(x_{1}) < f(x_{0}) < f(x_{2})$ for points $x_{1}, x_{2}$ in a certain neighborhood of $x_{0}$ with $x_{1} < x_{0} < x_{2}$. But this does not prove that there is any interval including $x_{0}$ throughout which $f(x)$ is a steadily increasing function, for the assumption that $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ lie on opposite sides of $x_{0}$ is essential to our conclusion.*"

However if $f'(x) > 0$ for all points $x$ of an interval $I$ then $f(x)$ is strictly increasing on interval $I$.

Comment: Although it is clear what you intend to say the remark "the derivative oscillates between $-\tfrac{1}{2}$ and $\tfrac{3}{2}$" is not clear (if true at all) since there is still the first term to consider for such a *precise* statement.

Comment: @WimC: When you take very small neighborhoods of $0$ the value of $x$ will be small and since $2x\sin(1/x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$, the contribution of this term in the value of $f'(x)$ will be smaller and smaller as $x$ becomes smaller and smaller.

Comment: @WimC: To further clarify I am not saying that $-1/2 \leq f'(x) \leq 3/2$ for small $x$. What I am saying is that there will a set of small values of $x$ for which $f'(x)$ will be near $-1/2$ and there will another set of small values of $x$ for which $f'(x)$ will be near $3/2$. It may happen that $f'(x) < -1/2$ and $f'(x) > 3/2$ for some of these values. Using precise symbolism we write $$\limsup_{x \to 0}f'(x) = \frac{3}{2},\,\liminf_{x \to 0}f'(x) = -\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: It is clear that that was intended, but it is *not* what you wrote. At least I am confused by the wording...

Comment: @WimC: I have edited my answer to make it more precise and less confusing.

Comment: "So any neighborhood of 0 contains some points a where f′(a)>0 and some other points b where f′(b)<0 [P1]. Thus it is not possible that f is increasing in any neighborhood of 0 [P2]."  How does P2 follow from P1? Is this some type of converse of the MVT? Can the deduction be made without the MVT?

Comment: @SRobertJames: you should be able to prove this just by definition of derivative: if $f$ is differentiable and increasing on an interval $I$ then the derivative $f'$ is non-negative on $I$. No MVT is needed here.